# What is a alternative for deprecated method \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadataInterface::getEntityConnection

Tags: magento2, model, magento2.3.2

I am currently implementing a **SaveHandler** class for my custom model like described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187919/70510). My goal is to save the relations between my custom model and the Store model.

There  `\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadataInterface::getEntityConnection` is used in order to get a connection. This method is deprecated since 100.1.0 but there's no alternative provided.

**Is there any alternative known?**

I've been looking around in core classes and in the SaveHandler for [pages](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/97a20273895280fed264065af690c208ffd1a2c0/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/ResourceModel/Page/Relation/Store/SaveHandler.php#L51) and [blocks](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/97a20273895280fed264065af690c208ffd1a2c0/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block/Relation/Store/SaveHandler.php#L51) it is still used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit too late, but hopefully will help someone.

I has the same problem while reproducing the Cms Block SaveHandler behavior. Instead of using the deprecated  `\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadataInterface::getEntityConnection`, I have used the `Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection`

```
<?php

namespace YourVendorName\YourModule\Model\ResourceModel\YourEntity\Relation\Store;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface;

class SaveHandler implements ExtensionInterface
{
    private ?AdapterInterface $connection = null;
    private ResourceConnection $resourceConnection;

    /**
     * @param ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute($entity, $arguments = [])
    {
        (...)
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        (...)
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the database
     *
     * @return AdapterInterface
     */
    private function getConnection(): AdapterInterface
    {
        if (!$this->connection) {
            $this->connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection('core_write');
        }
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```