# How to add store selector multi select field in admin form without using ui component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, magento2.4.2

I am trying to get store selector in admin form. I created this form without using ui component. I tried the below code but it didn't worked and I got the below error.

**The expected input field is:**

[image]

**The input field code is:**

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'store_view',
        'Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Form\Field\StoreView',
        [
            'label' => __('Store view'),
            'name' => 'store_view',
            'disabled' => false,
            //'class' => 'Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Form\Field\StoreView',
            'values' => $this->options->toOptionArray()
        ]
    );
```

In the above code `$this->options` is `"Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options"` class object.

**The error is:**

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException):
> Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Form\Field\StoreView doesn't extend
> \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
>
> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException):
> Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Form\Field\StoreView doesn't extend
> \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement #1
> Magento\Framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm->addField() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Fieldset.php:214]
> #2 Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset->addField() called at [app/code/Vital/CustomisedIntegrations/Preference/CustomisedForm.php:104]
> #3 Vital\CustomisedIntegrations\Preference\CustomisedForm->_addGeneralFieldset()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-integration/Block/Adminhtml/Integration/Edit/Tab/Info.php:53]
> #4 Magento\Integration\Block\Adminhtml\Integration\Edit\Tab\Info->_prepareForm()
> called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php:156]
> #5 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_beforeToHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1110]

**Note: I need the store selector in admin form without using ui component.
I found a related question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155021/magento-2-store-selector-for-custom-module-in-admin-form) but still didn't get a proper answers. please suggest me a better solutions**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    array $data = []
) {

    $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
    parent::__construct($context,$data);
}


 $fieldset->addField(
   'store_id',
   'multiselect',
   [
     'name'     => 'store_id[]',
     'label'    => __('Store Views'),
     'title'    => __('Store Views'),
     'required' => true,
     'values'   => $this->_systemStore->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
   ]
);
```